# How to interface with an H-bridge IC (L298N) using a single PWM pin

Tags: arduino, pwm, dc-motor, h-bridge, l298

I would like to know if it's advisable to control an H-bridge IC (L298N) using a single PWM pin?

Let me explain: By driving ENB pin High and by feeding complementary PWM (achieved by using a simple NPN transistor inverter circuit to invert PWM signal from Arduino) to IN1 and IN2, the dc motor connected to OUT1 and OUT2 is working (circuit schematic shown below).

[image: Circuit Schematic for Interfacing with a L298N using a single PWM pin]

In this setup, I am only using a single PWM: a duty cycle of 0% is maximum speed in one direction, a duty cycle of 100% is maximum speed in the other direction and a duty cycle of 50% stops the motor.

Apart from having a reduced resolution, everything seems to work. However all the tutorials online advise to use 3 pins to control L298N, with the PWM pin connected to ENB (for example this [Tutorial](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-dc-motor-control-tutorial-l298n-pwm-h-bridge/)). Why is this so? Is it not advisable to do what I did, using a single PWM pin?

Comment: adding a circuit schematic could help

Comment: you can totally do that single-PWM control with an H-Bridge that is designed for that. Generally, the L298N is a terrible IC by modern standards, and **so** many better alternatives exist that it makes little sense trying to make this work with an antique IC like the L298N. Simply don't use a L298N but something that does what you need, done.

Comment: Can you suggest some modern ICs ? I chose L298N because it was relatively cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this setup, I am only using a single PWM: a duty cycle of 0% is maximum speed in one direction, a duty cycle of 100% is maximum speed in the other direction and a duty cycle of 50% stops the motor.

That is not really what this is doing, no.

> Is it advisable to control an H-bridge IC (L298N) using a single PWM pin?
>   By driving ENB pin High and by feeding complementary PWM

Generally, yes, if your H-Bridge has built in circuitry that eliminates the time during which both transistors of one side of the H-Bridge are on, then you can do that.

The L298N doesn't, so there's a short amount of time where the inverter hasn't inverted yet, but the uninverted path has already been toggled, where that happens. And that shoot-through can damage you H-Bridge, lead to catastrophic flyback spikes on the power supply line etc.

So, you need a better H-Bridge controller.

Getting an H-Bridge controller that isn't the L298N (and thus, from the 1970s) also allows you to omit the inverter, and go fully digital.

So, good approach, bad component. For example, [TI](https://www.ti.com/motor-drivers/brushed-dc-bdc-drivers/overview.html) has a pretty large portfolio of motor drivers. Some you can just instruct to do what you want, and don't have to do any PWM yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I chose L298N because it was cheap and readily available for hobbyist

Comment: all these ICs are available, and I don't know how cheap your L298N was, but a device that doesn't do what you want (and your PWM forward/backward thing clearly won't work as intended) is always too expensive, no matter how cheap it is.